# jQuery UI autocomplete widget, and renderItem in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using the autocomplete widget to show a dropdown of suggestions when a user types in an input box.

- jQuery 1.10.2
- jQuery UI JS 1.11.2
- jQuery UI CSS 1.11.2

Everything seems to work great in Firefox (29.0.1) and Safari (7.0.6) but after several hours of trying different things, it doesn't seem to work in Chrome (38.0).

Edit: No warnings, no errors and no dropdown menu shows.

```
$("#MyInput").autocomplete({
    source: "/contacts/ajax_search.json"
}).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item){
    return $("<li>").append("<a>" + item.Contact.name + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
}
```

The data from `/contacts/ajax_search.json` looks like this;

```
[{"Contact":{"id":"1669","name":"Marta Smith"}}]
```

In Chrome, renderItem doesn't even seem to get called i.e. `console.log(item)` inside the function does nothing.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Instead of `data("uiAutocomplete")`, try `data("ui-autocomplete")`

Comment: Both `data("uiAutocomplete")` and `data("ui-autocomplete")` work in Safari and Firefox, but neither work in Chrome unfortunately!

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with how Chrome handles asynchronous ajax requests, as there's no option to set the autocomplete widget to makes requests synchronously via the standard options.

Solution is as follows, using a custom `source` function to fetch the data;

```
$("#MyInput").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/contacts/ajax_search.json?term=" + request.term,
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    }
}).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item){
    return $("<li>").append("<a>" + item.Contact.name + "</a>").appendTo(ul);
}
```